# How to open links not related to webview url in browser from app

Tags: android, kotlin

how can i open external links not related to webview url in browser, i am using kotlin lang to create android app in webview.
For eg. mydomain.com/ links should open in webview
       -notmydomain.com/ should open in browser

Comment: Don not set WebViewClient  to webview, by default all external links is redirected to browser

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webview.loadUrl("https://mywebsite.com")
        webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
        WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
    }
}

Comment: i only want links not related to my webview domain to open externally, for eg. mywebview domain - xyz.com/ - all links starting xyz.com should open internally. and all links not related to my webview domain like abc.com/ def.com/ should open externally

Answer (score 2):

```
val url = "http://www.example.com"
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
i.data = Uri.parse(url)
startActivity(i)
```

It works for me, use this in kotlin.

Comment: i only want links not related to my webview domain to open externally, for eg. mywebview domain - xyz.com/ - all links starting xyz.com should open internally. and all links not related to my webview domain like abc.com/ def.com/ should open externally

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

In below code we only load those urls which match specific domains rest of them are navigated to browser. You can customize the regular expression according to your need. Here i override two methods because of deprecation of **shouldOverrideUrlLoading** in api level 21.

```
val webview = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
        webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                val url: String = request?.url.toString()
                if (match(url,"(http|https)://(.*).kotlinlang.org/")) {
                    webview?.loadUrl(url)
                } else {
                    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    i.data = Uri.parse(url)
                    startActivity(i)
                }
                return true
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String): Boolean {
                if (match(url,"(http|https)://(.*).kotlinlang.org/")) {
                    webview?.loadUrl(url)
                } else {
                    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    i.data = Uri.parse(url)
                    startActivity(i)
                }
                return true
            }
        }
        webview.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/")
```

Comment: it shows error for match* and overline on shouldOverrideUrlLoading*

Comment: val webview = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
val url: String = request?.url.toString()
if (match(url,"(http|https)://(.*).mysite.com/")) {
webview?.loadUrl(url)
                } else {
                    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    i.data = Uri.parse(url)
                    startActivity(i)
                }
                return true
            }
        }

Comment: Following code not showing any error on my ide, what type of error your facing ,is this syntax or runtime error .  please verify you are importing the correct class for match and pattern   import java.util.regex.Matcher and
import java.util.regex.Pattern

Comment: Does it helps ? :)

Comment: is it possible to add 2 domains to url.contains or url.startswith ?

Comment: yes you can add by || operator first url.contains("first domain")||url.contains("second domain)

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

BTW Sometimes it may be also good to check if url is actually network URL e.g. you want to play store URL open by play application, not Webview loading play store page

```
URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(url)
```

Comment: this even opens links of my site in browser, i only want external links not related to my webview site domain to open externally.

Comment: You need to perform string filtering before starting activity and creating intent `if(!url.contains("mydomain.com"))`. As I recall you also need to return  true or false from 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading' in 'WebViewCient' regarding to the fact that you handled the link by yourself or not

Comment: is it possible to add 2 domains to url.contains or url.startswith ?